# Joomla using insert into a separate database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

```
$option = array();
$option['driver'] = 'mysql'; // Database driver name
$option['host'] = 'localhost'; // Database host name
$option['user'] = '*****'; // User for database authentication
$option['password'] = '********'; // Password for database authentication
$option['database'] = 'teste_dados'; // Database name
$db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
```

// Create a new query object.

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
```

/*
// Insert columns.

```
$columns = array('id_teste','testes','time');
```

// Insert values.

```
$values = array(4,'loucura3',date("h:i:s"));
```

// Prepare the insert query.

```
$query->insert($db->quoteName('teste1'));
$query->columns($db->quoteName($columns));
$query->values(implode(',', $values));
```

or

```
$query="INSERT INTO teste1('id_teste','testes','time') VALUES (4,'loucura3','".date("h:i:s")."')";
```

// Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Both options gives the following error message:

An error has occurred while processing your request.

You may not be able to visit this page because of:

```
an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a mistyped address
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
you have no access to this page
```

Go to the Home Page

Home Page

If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

```
 0 SQL=INSERT INTO teste1('id_teste','testes','time') VALUES (4,'loucura3','05:11:00')
```

I`ve seen some similar problems and their fixes and none of them workd for me any ideas?.

Comment: remove single quotes from the field name ->> INSERT INTO teste1('id_teste','testes','time')

Comment: Database tables in Joomla are defined with a prefix, for example, `jos_users` would become `#__users`. Have a look at the documentation to get a better idea of how database queries work

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the sql script in mysql workbench or phpMyAdmin. Use backticks instead of single quotes around columns